# parameter reference to pointer C++

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I was wondering what is the difference between

```
void foo(std::shared_ptr<A> a_){
   //work on a_
}
```

and

```
void bar(std::shared_ptr<A>& a_){
   //work on a_
}
```

?

Is the reference here useful to something? Since i'm working with side effect on `a_` I believe it wouldn't. But it is possible to write something like this so I'm really wondering.

Thanks!

Comment: It avoids the concurrency work needed to increment/decrement the shared pointer's reference count, and allows you to change/release the *callers* share-claim at-will. You can change the caller's shared pointer to point to something else, including nothing.

Comment: I believe I understood! Thanks!

Comment: Just make sure `a_` is not stored anywhere with a lifetime beyond the function call, and `bar` is not running in its own thread.

Comment: I do not understand your comment /: sorry ... Why should I take care about a_ not stored anywhere? If it's not stored, how can I work on it? *whistle*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works just like in case of any other data type, smart pointers are not different in this sense:

- When passing by value, you can work with a copy of the original object.
- When passing by reference, you can modify the original object.

See this simple example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct A {
    int a_;
    A(int a) : a_(a) {}
};

void foo_val(std::shared_ptr<A> a_){
    a_ = std::make_shared<A>(10);
}
void foo_ref(std::shared_ptr<A>& a_){
    a_ = std::make_shared<A>(10);
}

int main() {
   std::shared_ptr<A> pA = std::make_shared<A>(20);

   foo_val(pA);
   std::cout << pA->a_ << std::endl;
   foo_ref(pA);
   std::cout << pA->a_ << std::endl;   

   return 0;
}
```

It outputs `20, 10` showing that `foo_val` couldn't change original object, while `foo_ref` could.

[demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/918ca191ba6761a5)